# Centering multiple images over text

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I've been having a bit of difficulty trying to get an image centered over some text, something like this:

[image: Descriptive image goes here.]

I've made a few attempts using tables, but can't get the images to stay centered.

Comment: Thanks for the responses thus far and apologies because I haven't been clear in what I was asking, I said "over" when I meant above when referring to the centered text, which has led to some confusion.  http://www.albamclothing.com I would like to create an effect similar to the                                                                Meet us/find us/follow us/ask us/latest items text with images centered above the text.  I hope this has been made clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image's display property to block / inline-block allows you to use it like a normal object so you can set margin or padding. If you want to center it you could just use `display: block; 
margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFIDDLE example here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rye2W/)

You can use padding on your background so the text will always be in the center.
Also set `display: block;` or `inline-block;` so you can use `margins, padding` on it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color">
        <h1>Some big text</h1>
        <p>Some small text</p>
    </div>
</div>

.color{
    // background-color: red; <-- used in the jsfiddle
    background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

h1{
    font-size: 80px
}
```

Comment: Apoligies I haven't been clear in what I was asking, which has led to some confusion,

Comment: So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I would like to create an effect similar to the Meet us/find us/follow us/ask us/latest items text with images centered above the text. albamclothing.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="bannerinfo" style="color: white; width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color:#9fd2cd; text-align:center; line-height:40px;">
                       <p>Sale Now On - Click here to find out more</p></a>
</div>
```

try by this